# Video - can't hide timeline on safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, html5-video

I have a default HTML5 video player on site.

```
<video controls="controls">
  <source src="https://example.local/videos/video-1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> . 
</video>
```

The client wants to hide the timeline on the player.
So all controls should be displayed but without time control bar.

I have hidden timeline on all browser except safari by using CSS selector video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  display: none !important;
}
```

As I said before, it works on all browser, but not on safari.

Is there any way to hide the timeline in video on safari?

Thanks.

Comment: Wellcome to So, but can you put the code to help us to help you?

Comment: I have added my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display: none;
}
```

or

```
<video autoplay controls="false">
  <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

or just ignor user interactions:

```
video {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```